# is it possible to pass an array of objects as scope to angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I was wondering that if i can pass an array of objects to $scope of directive and when it occurs it shows different objects in array depending on there index in the array

eg

this is my directive template

```
<div id="myAdvert" style ="display: block">
    <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" >
      <img src="{{customer.image}}">
      <h2>{{customer.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{customer.address}}</p>
    </a>
</div>`
```

This is my directive

```
*angular.module('starter.Directives', [])
.directive('browseto', [function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'AEC',
      templateUrl: "templates/myadvert.html",
      replace: true,
       scope: {
         customer: '=info'
        }
   }
}]);
```

and in my controller if i pass the object array doesnt seem to work what i want is if the object array is passed then whenever the directive is shown its data should be the next object in array

i will post all the requirement so that i can make some sense :)

What i currently have is a  list of users and i want to show an ad after every 10(x) user is shown so i am using ng-repeat to loop the users and i am putting this directive inside that ng-repeat block and showing it after every 10(x) user using ngif

Now if i assign a single object to the $scope.customer in the controller of the view then the ad is same through out the view , what i want is that when the next directive shows up in the view it should contain a different ad thats why i wanted to assign an array of objects to the directive so after every 10(X) user there will be a different ad but it doesnt seem to work 
so how can i go ahead and achieve this

Thanks

Comment: please add some indentation to your code to improve readability :)

Comment: how you use `browseto` directive on page?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Template doesn't seem to have anything to do with using an array. It appears to expect an object. Also ...always use `ng-src` for images to avoid bad requests to strange url's with `{{}}` in them

Comment: <browseto "info=customer"> </browse> @PankajParkar

Comment: I dont see any array there, you are never using a repeter!

Comment: that is in the controller of the view where i am using this directive

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/AKuhOOpvlROexAjpv3XB?p=preview if you see here in the plunkr the controller assigns an object   @bto.rdz

Comment: i Hope i make some sence now @charlietfl